# Janino Compile Exception : UDJC step

Tags: pentaho, etl

Thanks in advance for your support.

In UDJC step, the following code gives me Janino exception,

In processRow method

```
Hashtable hastable=getConfigData() // This method return Hashtable 

Set set=hashtable.get("ERROR_2001").keySet(); ---> //hashtable.get("ERROR_2001"), This returns another hashtable
```

Exception:
A method named "keySet" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import

In forums I could not find the turn around solution to fix this. I am using JDK 1.7 and PDI 5.1 (latest download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't use generics in Janino, so Janino can not determine exact class of the object returned by `hashtable.get("ERROR_2001")` method, so it assumes that `Object` is returned, which has no `keySet()` method defined.
Try to cast the result of `hashtable.get("ERROR_2001")` to the value class, contained in your `hashtable` collection:

```
Hashtable errorEntry = (Hashtable) hashtable.get("ERROR_2001");
Set set = errorEntry.keySet();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I have done the same way what you said and all the errors gone.