# Janino generics issue in PDI

Tags: java, generics, pentaho-spoon, pdi, janino

I'm trying to code something in PDI which uses Janino for compilation.
This code

```
Element firstRow = doc.select("tr").first();
Elements headers = firstRow.select("td");
List list = headers.eachText​();
```

throws and error

```
A method named "eachText​" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
```

I know that Janino does not support generics, so I looked into this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34218510/8142420

> AFAIK, you can't use generics in Janino, so Janino can not determine exact class of the object returned by `hashtable.get("ERROR_2001")` method, so it assumes that `Object` is returned, which has no `keySet()` method defined. Try to cast the result of `hashtable.get("ERROR_2001")` to the value class, contained in your hashtable collection:
>
> `Hashtable errorEntry = (Hashtable) hashtable.get("ERROR_2001");
>   Set set = errorEntry.keySet();`

But that doesn't solve my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That doesn't sound like it's caused by generics. Are you sure you imported the jsoup `Elements` class and not the one from `javax.lang.model.util`?

Comment: @SeanVanGorder almost. It just got fussy without JAVA class name in front of it. Thanks :)